# Loopback indexes - how to specify different index types in model definition?

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs

In Loopback (v3), when defining indexes in my model.json files, how do I specify different types of indexes (such as a BRIN)? Also, how do I specify index conditions (such as if I want to create a partial index)? I'm using postgres for the database, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the index type via `type` field.

```
{
  "name": "MyModel",
  "properties": {
    // ...
  },
  "indexes": {
    "myindex": {
      "columns": "name, email",
      "type": "BRIN",
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

I am afraid LoopBack does not support index conditions (partial indexes) yet. Feel free to open a new issue in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-postgresql/issues.

Answer (score 2):

i was trying to add in Lb4. Its pretty straightforward there (should be same for lb3 as well i hope)

```
@model({ 
name: 'tablename', 
settings: {
 indexes: {
  idx_tablename: {
    columnA : '',
    columnB : '',
    columnC: ''
    }
   }
 } 
})
```

once the build is done, the index name idx_tablename with 3 columns will get created

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL and Loopback 3 you can specify an index for multi-column like this.

The following loopback JSON code creates index in Postgres with fields `message` and `type` are unique together.

```
{
  "name": "notification",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "message": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "seen": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "required": true,
      "default": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {},
  "indexes": {
    "message_type_index": {
      "keys": "message, type",
      "options": {"unique": true}
    }
  }
}
```